# Как убрать видимость блока в анимации?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Нужно, чтобы исчезал блок, но когда я делаю это через opacity, не могу ничего нажать, так как блок по сути все еще находится там, но прозрачный.

```
<body>
<header>
    <!-- header-->
</header>

<footer>
    <!-- footer-->
</footer>

<div class="over-all">
     <!-- Этот блок находится поверх остальных, после чего исчезает -->
</div>
```

```
.over-all {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: white;
animation-name: over-all2;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 0.8s;
animation-duration: 0.8s;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;


@keyframes over-all2 {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 0;
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста!

```
@keyframes over-all2 {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        padding-top: 0
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавляйте изменение по высоте, чтобы элемент не находился поверх остальных после анимации. Очень важно, чтобы начальное и конечное значения высоты были численными, иначе анимация не сработает (можно оставить `height: auto`, а манипулировать значениями `max-height`)

```css
header, footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: yellow
}

header {
  background: blue;
  border-bottom: 0;
}


.over-all {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  animation-name: over-all2;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes over-all2 {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <!-- header-->
</header>

<footer>
    <!-- footer-->
</footer>

<div class="over-all">
     <!-- Этот блок находится поверх остальных, после чего исчезает -->
</div>
```

Если вам неподходит анимация изменения высоты, можете манипулировать значениями z-index.

```css
header, footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: yellow
}

header {
  background: blue;
  border-bottom: 0;
}


.over-all {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  animation-name: over-all2;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes over-all2 {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <!-- header-->
</header>

<footer>
    <!-- footer-->
</footer>

<div class="over-all">
     <!-- Этот блок находится поверх остальных, после чего исчезает -->
</div>
```